# Bluetooth and Short Audio Source

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking to use an Arduino to monitor an incoming audio source (mobile radio/HAM/Walkie Talkie) for a transmission and send this stream through the car audio system speakers. Speaking back on the radio isn't important, but might explore using the car system for that as well.

My car provides the built in ability to listen to FM radio with my phone paired through bluetooth. When a call comes in on my phone, the car system detects and mutes the FM radio to play a ringtone from my phone over the car speakers. It also displays caller info, but I don't care about that for the radio audio. My car also has wired only Apple CarPlay. I would like to be able to plug my iPhone in through the cable for music streaming, and then connect my mobile radio through bluetooth to have the short messages mute the music and play the radio audio similar to the phone ring.

I am seasoned with Arduino but pretty new to bluetooth. Research so far looks like the ring and other actions happen through AT type of commands within the Headset Profile. Page 23 of the PDF below shows a RING command, but no ability to set the specific 'ringtone' if you will. Page 34 of the PDF suggests there is a way to set these ringtones or even an audio notification. Are these capable of relaying a live stream such as a mobile radio source?
Reference PDF: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN992.pdf

Is this something possible with a bluetooth module on Arduino?

The alternative scenario I can fall back on would be a Bluetooth middle man that can accept multiple audio signals (hopefully with bluetooth as an option), and then mute the primary source to play the secondary. I prefer above so I can use the CarPlay functions.